# How to enable ethernet interface with netplan on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, upgrade, 20.04

Recently, I have upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. After that, I am unable to access wired network connection but able to access wireless network.

See the output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

[image: network]

Comment: Is this a server or a desktop installation? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo ifconfig enp3s0 up`?

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and succeeded:

```
sudo ifconfig enp3s0 up
```

where `enp3s0` is the logical name for your Ethernet.